# Mapping Sales Data With ArcMap's Timeslider?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, time, animation, timeslider

I have some made-up data describing "Brenner" (a made-up brand) beer sales per bar, restaurant, supermarket (i.e. "Account"). The volume of beer is measured in cases. And, the time range is 4 weeks. I'm trying to create an animation, using the Timeslider tool in ArcMap 10.3, showing how the volume of Brenner beer cases changes per account week-to-week.

My inspiration is this: http://tipstrategies.com/geography-of-jobs/

So far, I've created a graduated symbol map for one week. This shows, basically, little dots for accounts with low sales and bigger dots for accounts with higher sales. What I want is to have the graduated symbols change *over time* - to reflect the sales per account week-to-week. From my trials, I can't seem to find a way to combine the time variable with another spatial-analysis tool (e.g. graduated symbols). It seems to be one or the other.

Does anyone have experience in this regard? Can you pass on some of your wisdom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I need to visualize data that changes over time I go back to the Help page called [About visualizing temporal data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/time/about-visualizing-temporal-data.htm) and follow the section that starts:

> **How to visualize temporal data**
>
> Any supported layer or table can be visualized over time by following
>   the steps below:

If you do this and get stuck, then just edit your question to list step by step precisely what you have done and where you are stuck.